# Wordpress broken image on admin edit

Tags: linux, wordpress

I am trying to figure this out , but cant get a accurate solution any where.
when I click edit the image is broken

I checked my functions.php for any white space, there is none.
I check if gd-modules are installed, they are installed.
I tried using a funtion to force the use of gd, but even that didnt work out.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you inspect that image element. What is the link you're getting? It might solve the problem to regenerate your thumbnails.

Comment: the image link also opens a broken image. :( 
sitedomin.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=3c6333f5a6&postid=19769&rand=67845

Comment: Have you tried regenerating the thumbs? https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen yes tried that, no positive results :(

Answer (score 0):

be sure to get installed phpx-gd this library is necesary to edit images, maybe too need imagick installed instead GD.